# Limit a query return columns with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

How do I limit a query to specific columns while using **Zend_Db_Table_Abstract**?

(getDbTable() below returns a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract object)

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(
       $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->where('forgienKey = \'' . $forgienKey . '\'')
        ->order("'id' ASC")
    );
```

I only need the id column returned but the entire row is returned. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) :

```
$select = $table->select();
$select->from($table, array('bug_id', 'bug_description'))
       ->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW');

$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

So, for you :

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(
       $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->from($this->getDbTable(), array('id'))
        ->where('forgienKey = \'' . $forgienKey . '\'')
        ->order("'id' ASC")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(
       $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->columns('id')
        ->where('forgienKey = \'' . $forgienKey . '\'')
        ->order("'id' ASC")
);
```

**EDIT**

Check the link

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

Comment: No go. This is why I posted the question because this does not work. The Zend manual states that you can specify columns but doesn't say how.

Comment: there's a `;` in line 3 where it shouldn't

Comment: The semi-colon is not the problem. Your answer looks like it should work but the generated query causes an error for me where as the answer that uses ->from does not. I believe that its the context of the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract that is causing the problem.